# How to change all uploaded image file extension from S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm trying to change the all uploaded image file extension. If image in .png,.gif,.jpeg, then it should be .jpg format. I don't want to download all image file from S3 bucket. I want to perform this process on S3 bucket itself. please let me know the right approach and solution for this.

Comment: To clarify: You wish to **convert** the file format from PNG to JPG and GIF to JPG, is that correct? And simply rename JPEG files to end with JPG?

Comment: Yes correct. But I want to perform this process on S3 bucket directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no capability in Amazon S3 to change the content of a file. There is no functionality to convert file formats.

An alternative method would be:

- Add a **Notification** to the S3 bucket to trigger a Lambda function when a new file is uploaded
- Define a **Lambda function** that checks the file format and, if necessary, converts the file and save it as a new object

Comment: THAT'S ACTUALLY A SOLUTION.